# How to rewrite a simple URL in Apache?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii2-basic-app, s3-rewrite-rules

If I have an URL like this:
http://localhost/sewacp/web/index.php

How can I eliminate /web/index.php so it'll be `http://localhost/sewacp`?

I wrote .htaccess like this but it didn't work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . web/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /sewacp/web/index.php [QSA,L]
```